# Inline Assembly in Netbeans using C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, inline-assembly

I'm attempting to learn assembly from a series of very good tutorials posted on youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guru397zg2g&list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D&feature=plcp&context=C4ca8d4cFDvjVQa1PpcFM2reYRFji1sQFkiYY545AxtksGRUnLWSY=

I'm familar with C++ and Java programming in netbeans and I am using the MinGW compiler set.
I have my C++ and assemblier compilers set in the netbeans complier properties.

My C++ code is compiling however using `_asm {}` to attempt inline assembly code isn't compling properly.

The error I recieve is :

```
main.cpp: In function 'int getValueFromASM()':

main.cpp:18:5: error: '_asm' was not declared in this scope

main.cpp:18:10: error: expected ';' before '{' token

make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2

make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

The code is:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int getValueFromASM()
{
    _asm {
        mov eax, 39
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Hello World from C++ !\n";

    cout << "ASM said " << getValueFromASM() << endl;

    cout << "Back in the program before close.\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Could someone point me in the direction of how to get inline assembly working in netbeans.

Comment: If you're using Windows, you might be better trying to download a free version of MS tools. I do not know the modern syntax for MS in-line assembler (20+ years since I did that sort of stuff with MS tools), but GNU in-line assembler will likely become increasingly different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the compilation error because you are using the wrong syntax.

Try changing your `getValueFromASM` method to this:

```
int getValueFromASM()
{
    asm("mov $39, %eax");
}
```

A good guide for inline assembly with GCC can be found here: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: Thanks, very useful guide.. Anoying that the AT&T version of assembly is almost the complete opposite of Intel assembly, but guess that just how it is.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically read about extended asm and clobbered registers
http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5

Also, Intel syntax is func dest,src, but ATT syntax(which is what gcc requires) has func src,dest